# Fractional Binary Number generation using Primitive Polynomial for Linear Feedback Shift Register

Tags: polynomials

Can primitive polynomial be used for generation of fractional binary random numbers for Linear Feedback Shift Register?

Comment: What is a "fractional random" number? Something that is midway between being predictable and random?

Comment: Fractional number which will be random e.g., 11.01, 1.001 etc.
Primitive polynomials are used to generate random binary numbers in LFSR. Can there be a structure which will generate a fractional binary number?